# Using Ajax GET returns zero when nothing is SELECTed from sql how can I have it return nothing in this case?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

Google Chrome doesn't seem to have this problem, I noticed this in Firefox.

So we start by using GET:

```
function execute_check(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        success: function(data){
            $("#div").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine if there is something being returned.

Then we have the PHP/mysql:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value='1' ORDER BY time ASC");
```

How can I have it return **NOTHING** rather than **0**? I also saw the same thing when I was using the `require()` function.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code (ie: what does ajax.php actually output)? And what do you mean by returning nothing? Do you mean the string `'NOTHING'`?

Comment: Dude, it's pretty obvious what is being asked. I'm sorry but it is right in front of you. Nothing being between the quotes: "". Nothing. And the output html isn't the focus. That doesn't have anything to do with it returning zero.

Comment: -1 For poorly worded question. It's **not** obvious and that's why I asked.

Comment: Actually Pete, NullUserException has an extremely valid point. `Nothing` could mean an empty sting, a zero-length string (`""`), an empty array, 0, or a string "nothing". You really shouldn't have such an attitude and closed mind when people are trying to help you.

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely to me that there'd be different behavior in this case between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: haha @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ comeon don't be an ass. Dutchie432 not really, that is over analyzing it. NOTHING not 0 I clearly stated this above. Deal with it.

Comment: Actually Pete, you are under-analyzing. YOU are the only one who knows what you want, and you have to properly explain it. "Nothing" is not a proper term for a return value. You've been down-voted 4 times for this poorly phrased question. Deal with it.

Comment: Yes by you guys. Go be a waste of space somewhere else if you can read what's right in front of you. Deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the [php](/questions/tagged/php) side, just add a check...

```
if ($resultCount==0) die(null);
```

or if you're using `require()` you'll want to use...

```
if ($resultCount==0) $resultCount=null;
```